# flash boot.img to use the kernel

Tags: boot, rom, partitions, kernel

why to flash a kernel i need a zipper anykernel 3? i can't flash directly the boot.img of a rom, example (PixelExperience) to have oniichan kernel on (LineageOS)? i'm absolutely new in the world of modding

Comment: because boot partition is a compose of kernel + ramdisk (not only kernel itself)